# intersection in vb

Tags: vba

why use we this statement if not intersect(...) is nothing then
but do not use intersect(...) is nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often when we use `intersect` we wish to know if two ranges intersect.
[Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) returns where these ranges intersect, but we often aren't interested in WHERE, but IF. So we ignore the returned value, and just check that we do get a value.

```
If Not Intersect() is Nothing Then
```

There's nothing stopping you from using it without the `Not`, even the documentation example is using it this way.
The reason why we usually don't do it in say, a `selection_change` is that the `If` returns true when the ranges do not intersect. And usually, we want to do things when they **do** intersect. This would make you end up with an empty `If`, and forcing you to use `else` as a trigger.
Consider the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    'Do things
End If
End Sub
```

Compared to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    'Do things
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: As a newbie to programming, one of my unanswered questions is why `Something` isn't a keyword. It would make so much sense to write `If Range Is Something Then` instead of `If Not Range Is Nothing Then`.

Comment: @Toddleson You could always make your own custom function `Something()` Although that would probably make it look like `If Something(Intersect(Target, Range("A1"))) Then` but still. `Not` is however useful in any situation where the above or similar situation would arise not only together with `nothing`.